# How to install 3rd party library "pymongo" for pypy3 2.1 Beta 1?

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, pymongo, pypy

I want to install pymongo for the pypy3 2.1 Beta 1. I'm using ubuntu. The [installation instruction](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#installing-pypy) says I should go through the following steps:

(1) $ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py

(2) $ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py

(3) $ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pypy distribute_setup.py

(4) $ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pypy get-pip.py

(5) $ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pip install pygments # for example

The first three steps are all OK (at least I didn't find any error messages). But when I execute step (4), there is an error:

`An error occurred while trying to run get-pip.py. Make sure you have setuptools or distribute installed`

What's the matter? How can I proceed to install pymongo in pypy3 2.1 Beta 1? In addition, since I'm using python3, I installed the pymongo library designed particularly for python3 using python3-pip (pip-3.3). Do I need to modify the above installation steps accordingly to accommodate pymongo for python3? Thank you.

Comment: Try installing setuptools. Distribute is now defunct.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro : Thank you for the comment. I installed the setuptools and passed the step (4). However, it's now step (5)'s turn to give me an error. Could you please take a look at the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477583/pip-isnt-working-when-importing-something Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) by downloading [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and running it from the target Python interpretator (cpython, pypy or etc.).
Installation error may occur in case you have not defined `PYTHONPATH` then you should set `PYTHONPATH` to the `site-packages` directory of your target Python interpretator, for example:

```
PYTHONPATH="/opt/pypy3/site-packages"  /opt/pypy3/bin/pypy ./ez_setup.py
```

Or export `PYTHONPATH` as environment var.
Then you should be able to successfully install `get-pip.py`:

```
PYTHONPATH="/opt/pypy3/site-packages"  /opt/pypy3/bin/pypy ./get-pip.py
```